# Efficient way to fill column of a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, fill

If found that complexity of std::fill for std::vector is [constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

> Complexity
> Linear.
>
> However, if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of LegacyRandomAccessIterator, complexity is constant.

so I have  a 2D vector and i can fill first row with constant time

```cpp
std::fill(mat[0].begin(), mat[0].end(), 0)
```

is it possible to do the same for the first column without a loop like this?

```cpp
for(size_t i = 0; i < m; i++) mat[i][0] = 0;
```

can i fill faster than linear time maybe with memset?

Comment: The page you linked is for `std::distance`, not [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)... Also, memset will not ever change a complexity from linear to constant. That's not how complexity works.

Comment: You seemed to misclick the browser tab. You have quoted `std::distance`. *Exactly std::distance(first, last) assignments* means the complexity is N*O(1), where N is the number of elements between end and begin, i.e. O(N).

Comment: @Nelfeal The page of [fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) links there, saying the complexity is same, sorry for confusion

Comment: @273K Alright, thanks for making that clear!

Comment: It doesn't say the complexity is the same. `std::distance(first, last)` is just a number. Nothing to do with the complexity of calling `std::distance`.

Comment: I recommend fixing the link. The less confusion you cause future readers the more useful the question will be. Writing useful content is its own reward, but Stackoverflow rewards usefulness with upvotes and more site privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment for `std::fill` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) says:

> Complexity 
> Exactly std::distance(first, last) assignments.

This does not mean that complexities of `std::fill` and `std::distance` are the same, as you seem to believe. It means that the complexity of `std::fill` is proportional to the number of elements in the range `[first, last)` and for each such element an assignment operator is executed. Consequently, the time complexity of `std::fill` is linear in the number of assignments. However, the algorithm is generic so you do not know what the iterators it works on (e.g., `first`) actually represents and if the assignment operator (which may be an overloaded, user-defined one) really assigns any value to anything. It might, for example, print the value to `std::cout`. That's why, I believe, the description in the reference text does not refer to the number of elements being modified in some container (which need not exist at all), but to the number of assignments.